# How can I create a pixel labelled image for Semantic Segmentation?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision

I am following the [Semantic Segmentation Examples](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/semantic-segmentation-examples.html#mw_44be2a2e-ec6b-4a03-9470-ea945f74515e) tutorial by MathWorks.

I understand that I can load pixel labeled images

```
pxDir = fullfile(dataDir,'buildingPixelLabels');
```

Define the class names.

```
classNames = ["sky" "grass" "building" "sidewalk"];
```

Define the label ID for each class name.

```
pixelLabelID = [1 2 3 4];
```

and create a pixelLabelDatastore.

```
pxds = pixelLabelDatastore(pxDir,classNames,pixelLabelID);
```

But, how do I **create a custom pixel labelled image** where every pixel value represents the categorical label of that pixel?

I would then proceed by writing:

```
pxDir = fullfile(dataDir,'myCustomPixelLabels');
```

If I understood correctly, `imageDatastore` holds the actual image and not the pixel labels for that image.

---

**EDIT:**

On my system `pxDir` points to `'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2017a\toolbox\vision\visiondata\buildingPixelLabels'`. Since I am on Matlab2017a so this example is not included by default, and I cannot compare or view the file to get a better understanding of what I need to do to reproduce this example.

Comment: Isn't that what the tutorial does just there after the last line you got from it?

Comment: Actually, this is what exactly happening at `pxds = pixelLabelDatastore(pxDir,classNames,pixelLabelID);`

Comment: @NoumanRiazKhan but `pxDir` loads the pixel labeled image, and that is what I'm asking about. How would one go about creating `myCustomPixelLabels`

Comment: @AnderBiguri so imds = imageDatastore(imDir); represents the image data where I need to label the pixels?  How would this look like since `imageDatastore` is usually used to manage a collection of image files.

Comment: @AnderBiguri `imageDatastore`  holds the actual image and not the pixel lables for that image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer can be found [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/get-started-with-the-image-labeler.html).

**Matlab 2017a**

Go to the **APPS** tab, and search for `Image Labeler`, or `Training Image Labeler`

Click on `Add Images` to add your training images.

Click on `Add ROI Labels` to add class names for the regions of interest.

Proceed to select the regions of interest manually from the uploaded images.

Once areas are selected, the data can be exported to workspace as a Ground Truth object.